# Press Button, Change Label Colour

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to be able to change a label's background colour when a button is pressed. I currently have the following code.

```
def violet_btn():
    bg = 'violet'

def violet_label():
    if violet_btn == True:
        color = 'violet'
    else:
        color = 'grey'
violet_l = Label(the_window, bg = 'grey', height= 1, width = 8)
violet_l.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=3)

violet = Button(the_window, text = 'Violet', height= 1, width = 8, command = violet_label)

violet.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=3)
```

I know it's not complicated enough, but I'm new to python and am not sure what else to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the button's `configure()` method; use `cget()` to read the current colour so you can easily toggle between two:

```
def violet_label():
    current = violet.cget('bg')
    new_colour = 'violet' if current == 'grey' else 'grey'
    violet.configure(bg=new_colour)
```